# Aop, Unity, Interceptors and ASP.NET MVC Controller Action Methods

Tags: .net, log4net, unity-container, aop

Using log4net we would like to log all calls to our ASP.NET MVC controller action methods.

The logs should include information about any parameters that were passed to the controller.

Rather than hand-coding this in each action method we hope to use an AoP approach with [Interceptors via Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd140045.aspx).

We already have this working with some other classes that use interfaces (using the `InterfaceInterceptor`). However, we're not sure how to proceed with our controllers. Should we re-work them slightly to use an interface, or is there a simpler approach?

### Edit

The [VirtualMethodInterceptor](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/VirtualMethodInterceptorUnity12CastleDynamicProxyFans.aspx) seems to be the correct approach, however using this results in the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: str
   at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.Emit(OpCode opcode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen <strike>[this](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/07/14/CustomActionFilterLoggingApplicationBlock.aspx)</strike> <sup>[link broken]</sup>

#### Following is an excerpt from the broken/missing blog post courtesy of David Hayden

Here is a `LogFilterAttribute` that uses the **Enterprise Library Logging Application Block**'s `LogWriter` for logging messages.

```
public class LogFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public LogWriter Logger { get; set; }
 
    public string Category { get; set; }
 
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string message = string.Format(
            "{0} ActionMethod on {1}Controller executing...",
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName);
 
        var category = Category ?? "General";
 
        Logger.Write(new LogEntry {
            Message = message,
            Categories = new[] { category }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark, this link is broken, because David Hayden decided for some reason to *start anew* and remove all previous blog content. What a stupid decision. Your answer is now unfortunately completely unusable. Let me try and make it at least a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly what you are asking, but you might want to consider [log4postsharp](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/wiki/Log4PostSharp). maybe you will need [this](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/wiki/PostSharpAspNet) as well, but I cannot tell for sure as I did not use ASP.Net MVC so far